# "Sorry, something went wrong" when trying to "Set up nearby device"

Tags: backup, nexus-5, data-transfer, bugs

I have a new Google Nexus 5X model LH-H790, that's meant to replace an also new Nexus 5X LG-H791.

When I try to transfer the account from phone to phone ("Set up nearby device") I see the confirmation code as expected on both phones.  Pressing next gives the unhelpful error message ***"Sorry, something went wrong".***

The devices are next to each other, or nearby, or touching, both connected to the same WiFi, and both machines are virtually new.  What could cause "Sorry, something went wrong"?

Comment: Wild guess... Are the batteries in both devices sufficiently charged ? It may not be working since transfer apps, contacts etc may be time consuming and is expecting the battery to support?

Comment: Try removing previously paired blue tooth devices on the old phone. See [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/help/transfer-nexus-4-setting-to-nexus-6p-t3261736)

Comment: @beeshyams both batteries are fully charged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Did a lot of things and something finally worked:

1) deleted all known bluetooth devices on old phone

2) physically moved devices that were close and showing up

3) restarted old phone after ^

4) factory restarted the new phone after the failed attempts

5) touched the phones together sideways so their backs perfectly aligned (the camera lens was creating a gap)

I was using android 6.0 on one phone and 7.0 on the new, so that shouldn't be a deal breaker.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue today. I had to replace my old (broken) Nexus 5X to a new Nexus 5X.

After unsucessfull tries (same error message as you) I started to all reconfigure manually when I noticed my old Nexus 5X was running Android 7.0 and the new stock Nexus 5X was still on Android 6.0.

So here is what I did: I accepted the update to Android 7.0, then did a factory reset on the new phone and I restarted the procedure and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, here they are both on 7.0.  But,  one has 7.0 patches pending so might try that.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue transferring from my old 5x to my new replacement 5x. It turned out the new phone was on OS version 7.0 while my old phone was on 7.1.1. So I downloaded and installed the update to 7.1.1 on the new phone, did a factory reset on the new phone (which still keeps system updates but deletes user data), tried again, and voila! It worked.

**tl;dr make sure both phones are on the newest, most updated version of the OS, do a factory reset on the new phone, and try again.**